# How to deploy Profile with .net Core app on AWS

Tags: .net-core, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

**NOTE: This question is for a .net core console application, *not ASP.NET Core.***

I am confused on the proper use of a Profile on AWS.  What I understand is that AWS would prefer that a profile name is used *instead* of a file containing AWS credentials (aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key) values.

With .net core, how will I know how to navigate to the users home directory where the credentials file should be stored? (According to this reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html#using-a-credentials-file

I am creating a .net Core application to connect to Amazon Kinesis and will be deploying it in a Docker container.  I want to be able to deploy and have the application find the credentials on its own using `.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonKinesis>()`.  From what I understand, this approach allows `AWSOptions` to lookup/find the credentials under the covers by locating the credentials file.

Please help me understand how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the docker container you will be deploying to hosted in ECS? If so, using the [IAM Roles for Tasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) feature in ECS will be the simplest solution to your question.

Essentially, you can configure an IAM role that the task/container will run under, and configure it's permissions by assigning an IAM policy to that role. ECS manages the process of providing credentials for that role to the docker container. The SDKs will all pick up the credentials ECS provides by default, unless you explicitly override them by providing credentials while creating a client or change your credential provider chain.

We published a blog post about ECS IAM roles for tasks when we launched the feature:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/07/amazon-ec2-container-service-now-supports-iam-roles-for-tasks/

Comment: Thanks @Ben Walters.  So how do you dev locally while accessing a resource in AWS that does not have a local version (in this case Amazon Kinesis)?  Will I have to use a credential file approach and just not deploy that type of configuration when adding it to a Docker container?

Comment: You have several options, see [Configuring Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html) for the full detail. Credential files or environment variables are probably the easiest for your use case. Both should let you keep the code 100% the same between your dev environment and production/CD pipeline environments.